# VBA Userform works when run directly but not when run through sub

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm that prompts the user to both to select a file (*Application.FileDialog(.soFileDialogOpen)*) and to click a couple of options (various *checkboxes*). Both of these are required, so I want the OK button to only be enabled if a file has been selected and at least one checkbox has been clicked. I have a sub (*CheckAndEnable*) that runs both after a file is selected and after any checkbox is clicked (I am using a class to handle this).

Here is a very simplified version of the userform code. The userform has a button called **buttonOK**, a button that selects a file **buttonSelectFile**, and a variable number of checkboxes.

```
Option Explicit
Dim colChkboxes As Collection
Dim intchoice As Integer, AtLeastOneChecked As Boolean, strPath As String

Private Sub buttonOK_Click()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub buttonSelectFile_Click()
    Dim intchoice As Integer

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intchoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    If intchoice <> 0 Then
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        labelPath.Caption = strPath
    End If

    CheckAndEnable
End Sub

Public Sub CheckAndEnable()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    ' checks all checkboxes to determine if at least one is checked    
    AtLeastOneChecked = False
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctrl.Value = True Then
                AtLeastOneChecked = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    ' enable the OK button if file selected and at least one checkbox clicked
    If (AtLeastOneChecked = True) And (Not IsEmpty(strPath)) And (strPath <> "") Then
        buttonOK.Enabled = True
    Else
        buttonOK.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    buttonOK.Enabled = False
    ' declare vars
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim obj As clsCheckBox

    Set colChkboxes = New Collection
    ' set each checkbox to CheckBox Class that handles if checkbox is 
clicked.
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            Set obj = New clsCheckBox
            obj.AssignClicks ctrl
            colChkboxes.Add obj
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

I also have a Class Module **clsCheckBox** with the following code, which calls CheckAndEnable whenever a checkbox is clicked.

```
Private WithEvents chkbox As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Sub AssignClicks(ctrl As Control)
    Set chkbox = ctrl
End Sub

Private Sub chkbox_Change()
    Call MyUserform.CheckAndEnable
End Sub
```

When I run the UserForm directly, everything works beautifully. The problem is that when I call the userform in a module (this userform is part of a series of userforms in a larger script), the CheckAndEnable script runs when checkboxes are clicked but doesn't enable the OK button as it is supposed to. I have researched this extensively but haven't been able to find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you launching the userform as `MyUserform.Show` or creating an instance of it an then launching it? For example `Dim frm as new MyUserform` and then `frm.Show`?

Comment: It works correctly if I launch the userform using `MyUserform.Show`. The problem is that this userform is only sometimes displayed (depending on an earlier form), so I have been using `Set frm = VBA.UserForms.Add("MyUserform")` and then `frm.Show` because that allows me to flexibly call the userform and others in a loop as necessary.

Comment: Aha! That's what it was. I replaced `Call MyUserform.CheckAndEnable` with `Call chkbox.Parent.CheckAndEnable` and now it works without issue. Thank you both!

Comment: Yes `Call MyUserform.CheckAndEnable` creates a problem if you do the latter as mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `MyUserform.CheckAndEnable` in the `chkbox_Change()` sub of `clsCheckBox`, it runs the CheckAndEnable script for the **default** instance of the UserForm. Since the module showing the userform was creating a non-default instance of the form, the CheckAndEnable script was failing because it had no knowledge of what checkboxes/variables/etc had been changed in the non-default version.

Thanks to Mathieu Guindon for the solution. See [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for more details.